# VueJs no me esta subiendo la imagen a mi backend (laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fileupload, archivo

tengo un problema con la subida de imagenes desde VueJS a laravel.

La subida la hago con **axios** de la siguiente manera:

```
 let formData = {
                        nombre: this.currentPersona.nombre,
                        apellido_1: this.currentPersona.apellido_1,
                        apellido_2: this.currentPersona.apellido_2,
                        genero_id: this.currentPersona.genero.id,
                        fecha_nacimiento:this.currentPersona.fecha_nacimiento,
                        fecha_fallecimiento:this.currentPersona.fecha_fallecimiento,
                        padre:this.currentPersona.padre.id,
                        madre:this.currentPersona.madre.id,
                        hijos:this.hijos,
                        imagenes:this.imagenes,
                        pdfs:this.pdfs,
                    };
                    axios.post('/persona', formData, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data === true) {
                            that.toast('Guardado correctamente !','success');
                        }
                        else{
                            that.toast('Error al guardar!','error');
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        that.toast('Error critico! = '+error,'error');
                    });
```

Todos los datos me llegan al backend bien, menos los ficheros. Bueno ¿y que es imagenes? Bueno pues pues esa variable se auto-rellena con el evento onchange de su input file, al lanzar el onchange llama a la siguiente funcion:

```
 preSubirImagenes(e){

                let algunFicheroNoAceptado = false;

                var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;

                for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                    let currentFile = files[index];

                    if (
                        currentFile.type === 'image/jpg' ||
                        currentFile.type === 'image/jpeg' ||
                        currentFile.type === 'image/png'
                        ){

                        let newItemFile ={
                            file_full:currentFile,
                            nombre:currentFile.name,
                            url:URL.createObjectURL(currentFile)
                        };

                    this.imagenes.push(newItemFile);

                    }
                    else{
                        algunFicheroNoAceptado = true;
                    }

                }

                if (algunFicheroNoAceptado) {
                    this.toast('Algun fichero no tiene la extension permitida para las imagenes','error');
                }

            }
```

Esta funcion basicamente me deja la variable imagen algo parecido a esto :

```
(3) […]
​
0: {…}
​​

​​
file_full: File { name: "foto_so_2.png", lastModified: 1592060733213, size: 7576, … }
​​
nombre: "foto_so_2.png"
​​
url: "blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/b70f3fcf-cba3-43b7-b731-91892ed40ede"

​
1: {…}
​​
file_full: File { name: "foto_so_1.png", lastModified: 1592060651092, size: 8352, … }
​​
nombre: "foto_so_1.png"
​​
url: "blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/e0050926-e129-49c3-94a4-dfbbe441d051"
​​
​
2: {…}

file_full: File { name: "commits.png", lastModified: 1584220738380, size: 67349, … }
​​
nombre: "commits.png"
​​
url: "blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/eb9a4a32-5bcd-4216-b0f9-4e039c51b634"
​
​
length: 3
​
```

La estrucutra de ese array es un JSON con los siguientes campos:

- File full: Aqui guardo todo el fichero, se supone que esta todo el binario y el que se supone que usare para guardar en mi servidor
- Nombre: el nombre real del archivo
- Url: una url temporal para que se vea una miniatura de la foto que se esta intentando subir

Hasta aqui seria lo que es mi **FRONTEND**.

Ahora en el backend, la parte que ocupa la **obtencion del fichero** es la siguiente:

```
   $imagenes = $request->file('imagenes');
```

Y no me detecta los archivos. No se porque no lo detecta la verdad. Deberia.